# Getting First digit in double and storing it in an int C++

Tags: c++, int, double, static-cast

Hello im coding in C++ and i need some help with converting a double to an int.
what a need is a way to get the first number from a double ie (3.5945) "3".
and put that number into an int.

I'm using static_cast now and its returning a 0.

```
double X = 3.1234;
double Y = 4.3455;

int myIntX =  static_cast <int>(X);
int myIntY =  static_cast <int>(Y);

cout << myIntX << endl;
cout << myIntY << endl;
```

output....

0
0

Comment: Please provide an example that reproduces your problem. This one doesn't: http://ideone.com/zOlRz

Comment: The code you have pasted does not have your bug. The bug must be in the code you *didn't* paste. Please produce a **short**, **complete** sample program that demonstrates the problem. See http://sscce.org

Comment: my double number is actually this .... not sure what that means 3.89082e-316

my program is fairly large and the double and int variables are within that class.

Comment: 3.89082e-316 is 0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000389082. Of course the integral part of that is 0.

Comment: ohk thanks alot i must be looking at the wrong place then.it must be when i calculate the double

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
double x=3.1234;
int myintx=(int)x;

while(myintx%10!=0)
myintx/=10;

cout<<myintx;
```

This will give you the first digit your double as an int.